# Build shopping cart functions with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, dom, cart

I am trying to build a shopping cart function.

I have a product page, that displays API data. When pressing the "Add to cart" button, the item should be added to local storage, and fetched from local storage to build the html content for the shopping cart.

The cart page should display this:
A list of all products added to the cart, each item must include a title, price, a link to the product view page and a product image.

If the cart is empty I want to display a message indicating this.

After the list of products, i want to display the total price of all the products in the cart.

Here is the combined code for the productDetail page and all cart functions that I have built so far.

```
import { baseUrl } from "../../constants/api.js";
import displayMessage from "../displayMessage.js";

// const productsURL = baseUrl + "/products";

const queryString = document.location.search;
const params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const id = params.get ("id");
let cartArray = [];

if(!id) {
    document.location.href ="./index.html";
}

const productsUrl = baseUrl + "/products/" + id;
const results = await fetch(productsUrl);
const details = await results.json();

export async function productDetails() {

    try {
        // const response = await fetch(productUrl);
        // const details = await response.json();
        document.title = details.name;

        const productContainer = document.querySelector(".product__card");

        productContainer.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${baseUrl + details.image.url}" class="card-img-top rounded-0 card__image" alt="${details.image.name}">
        <div class="card-body p-0 pt-2 details">
            <h2 class="">${details.title}</h2>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div class="card product__details">
                    <div class="details__header p-0 mt-2">
                        <p class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left p-0 m-0 text-decoration-none text-transform-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                <span class="padding__wrapper details__btn">Details</span>
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body details__text">
                            ${details.description}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text mt-2 details__price">
                $${details.price}
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 shadow-none cart__button" data-product="${details.id}" type="button">
                <span class="padding__wrapper">Add to cart</span>
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
            </button>
        </div>`;

        const addCartButton = document.querySelectorAll("button.cart__button");
        console.log(addCartButton);

        addCartButton.forEach(function(button){
            button.onclick = function(event) {
                console.log(button);
                cartArray.push(event.target.dataset.product); 
                console.log(cartArray);
            //    this line should look inside the function that loops the html and finds the item with the correct id
                // const itemToAdd = details.find(item => item.id === event.target.dataset.product);
                // console.log(itemToAdd);
                // cartArray.push(itemToAdd);
                // showCart(cartArray);
                // localStorage.setItem("cartList", JSON.stringify(cartArray));
            }
        });

    }catch(error) {
        displayMessage("error", "Error when loading the product", ".product__card");
    }

};

function showCart(cartItems) {
    const cartContainer = document.querySelector(".cart__container");
    const totalContainer = document.querySelector(".total__container");

    cartContainer.innerHTML = "";
    let total = 0;

    cartItems.forEach(function (cartElement) {
        total += cartElement.price;
        cartContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="loading"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <a href="#"><img src="${baseUrl + cartElement.image.url}" class="card-img cart__product__image" alt="${cartElement.image.name}"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="${cartElement.id}"><h5 class="card-title">${cartElement.title}</h5></a>
                            <p class="card-text">$${cartElement.price}</p>
                            <div class="row edit__amount">
                                <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                                <div class=""></div>
                                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
    })

    totalContainer.innerHTML = 
    `<h2>Order Summary</h2>
    <p>You order:</p>
    <div class="table-responsive table-sm">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Subtotal:</td>
                <td>$${total}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shipping:</td>
                <td>Free Shipping</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="table-responsive table-sm">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>$${total}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">To Checkout</a>`;

};
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is the question?  Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation. I just dont know how to connect the code and actually build a functioning cart. I have code fragments above, but it doesn't actually work yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.